# Javascript - Optimal way to get maximum sum of arrays in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
   arr = [
     [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
     [ 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 ],
     [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
     [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
     [ 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2 ],
     [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 4 ],
     [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4 ],
     [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0 ],
     [ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
     [ 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2 ],
     [ 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0 ],
     [ 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0 ],
     [ 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1 ],
     [ 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2 ],
     [ 2, 4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 4 ],
     [ 4, 4, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0 ]
  ]
```

Currently, I'm getting the max array sum in `arr` i.e 19 like this

```
   function getMaxSum(arr) {
      return arr.map(e => e.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)).sort((a,b) => a - b)[arr.length - 1];
   }
```

- I need to know is there any better way to achieve this?
- I'm using array length of the original array to get the last element of resulting array because in this case, length of original array and resulting array is same. If the scenario is different then how can I use the length of the resulting array here:

  return arr.map(e => e.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)).sort((a,b) => a - b)[***HERE*** - 1];

Comment: What "cost" the most is the `sort()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimal strategy should be one where we need the least interaction with the arrays.

In my method i test the array products individually and compare that with a variable inside my loop. In this way i don't need to run a new implied loop to have `Math.max` check all my entries again, netting a speed boost.

This also saves on memory management as i don't need to map and return a new array of results for `Math.max`.

At the end of the loop i simply return the variable.

```js
var data = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2],
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 4],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2],
    [1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2],
    [2, 4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 4],
    [4, 4, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0]
];
function getMaxSum1(arr) {
    //The original method
    return arr.map(function (e) { return e.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0); }).sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; })[arr.length - 1];
}
function getMaxSum2(arr) {
    //From https://stackoverflow.com/a/51704254/5242739
    return Math.max.apply(Math, arr.map(function (e) { return e.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0); }));
}
function sumArray(arr) {
    var val = 0;
    for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
        val += val;
    }
    return val;
}
function getMaxSum3(arr) {
    //My method
    var max;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var val = sumArray(arr[i]);
        if (max === void 0 || val > max) {
            max = val;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
//TEST
//parameters
var runs = 10;
var tests = 100000;
//output area
var out = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("pre"));
//test functions
function simulate1() {
    var t = tests;
    var dt = Date.now();
    while (t--) {
        getMaxSum1(data);
    }
    out.textContent += 'getMaxSum1 took: ' + (Date.now() - dt) + "ms\n";
    requestAnimationFrame(simulate2);
}
function simulate2() {
    var t = tests;
    var dt = Date.now();
    while (t--) {
        getMaxSum2(data);
    }
    out.textContent += 'getMaxSum2 took: ' + (Date.now() - dt) + "ms\n";
    requestAnimationFrame(simulate3);
}
function simulate3() {
    var t = tests;
    var dt = Date.now();
    while (t--) {
        getMaxSum3(data);
    }
    out.textContent += 'getMaxSum3 took: ' + (Date.now() - dt) + "ms\n\n";
    if (runs--) {
        requestAnimationFrame(simulate1);
    }
}
//start
simulate1();
```

```css
pre {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

I included [OliverRadini's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51704204/51704254#51704254) to compare the relative speed boosts.

Comment: Thanks man. That's perfect. Upvoted it, Any help for my second point would be appreciated as well. :)

Comment: @AbdulRafay As i understood your second point, it sorts the list of products and returns the last element, which would be the biggest. Isn't this redundant if you already have the biggest result?

Comment: I just need to know if it's possible to use resulting array length in this line:
return arr.map(e => e.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)).sort((a,b) => a - b)[HERE - 1];

Comment: @AbdulRafay The array should be of the same length, so yes that will work in your example

Comment: asking for the scenario of different length. I'm guessing the answer is that you cannot access resulting array length here, but I wanted to double check.

Comment: If you are worried about the length shifting and you don't want to allocate a variable, you could simple use `ARRAY.reverse()[0]` to get the "_last_" element.

Comment: exactly that's what I'm worried about. I thought same to use array.reverse but was wondering what if there's a requirement to access length.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177583/discussion-between-emil-s-jorgensen-and-abdul-rafay).

Answer (score 4):

Not a huge improvement, but it seems a little more literal to spread the values into `Math.max`

```js
const data = [
     [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
     [ 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 ],
     [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
     [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
     [ 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2 ],
     [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 4 ],
     [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4 ],
     [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0 ],
     [ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
     [ 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2 ],
     [ 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0 ],
     [ 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0 ],
     [ 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1 ],
     [ 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2 ],
     [ 2, 4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 4 ],
     [ 4, 4, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0 ]
  ]

function getMaxSum(arr) {
  return Math.max(...arr.map(e => e.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)))
}

console.log(getMaxSum(data))
```

---

As @Rajesh points out, Math.max is faster that a sort:

```js
const numbers = Array(10000).fill().map((x,i)=>i);

const max = numbersIn => Math.max(...numbersIn);
const getMaxViaSort = numbersIn => numbersIn
  .sort((a, b) => a > b ? -1 : 1)[0]

console.time('max');
max(numbers);
console.timeEnd('max');

console.time('max via sort');
getMaxViaSort(numbers);
console.timeEnd('max via sort');
```

Comment: Actually, `Math.max` is way faster than using a loop. So it should have significant boast. Also, `Array.sort` is expensive, avoiding that will also help a lot

Comment: Thanks, that's really good to know; I've updated my answer to illustrate that

Comment: Thanks for the response and reminding me about Math.max. I've upvoted your answer. I'll be glad if you could help me with my second point too. :)

Comment: Do you mean `return arr.map(e => e.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)).sort((a,b) => a - b)[HERE - 1];`?

Comment: yes. I just need to know if it's possible to use resulting array length in this line.

Comment: I'm not sure why you still need that with these other solutions?

Comment: asking it for some other scenario. It should be a separate SO question i guess. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Are you only looking to get the last item in an array?